# Clarify the behaviour of << operator overloading of in C++

Tags: c++

Here is the programm:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class X {
int no;
public:
    X(int n=1) : no{n} {}
    X(const X& rop) : no{rop.no * 11} {}
    void f(X x, X& y);
    ostream& print(ostream& o) const {return o << no;}
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const X& x) {
    return x.print(o);
}
void X::f(X x, X& y) {
    ++no; ++x.no; ++y.no;
    cout << *this << x << y;
}
int main()
{
    X a, b{5}, c{6};
    a.f(b, c);
    cout << a << b << c;
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the output: 267257

But instead I got: 2567257

It seems, that this strage(for me) behaviour is connected with `cout << x`, but I cannot understand why `cout << x` outputs `56` instead of just `6`?

Comment: You can't expect a 1-digit number after multiplying by 11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter `x` is declared as pass-by-value; it will be copied from the argument `b`. According to the copy constructor of `X`, the data member `no` is initialized as `rop.no * 11` then it'll be `55`. After `++x.no;`, you'll get `56`.
Pass-by-value also explains why after the invocation of `a.f` `b.no` remains `5`, because `x` is a copy and any modification on it has nothing to do with the argument `b`.

On the other hand, `y` is declared as pass-by-reference, then there's no copy and copy constructor isn't called. Then for `y.no` you'll get the value of `6`, after `++y.no` it'll be `7`. And after the invocation of `a.f` `c.no` becomes `7` too.